# Count records with values in a specific range

Tags: ms-access

I have a database with that shows invoices and how long it took to pay them. We grade according to the age of the invoice. I have a report set up that shows the employee their min time max time total of records. However, I am having a hard time adding the value that counts all records greater than 14 days and then another that counts all records less than or equal to 14 days. My total records equation is `=Count([MaxOfAge])`. That successfully brings out the total number of records I have tried `=Count([MaxOfAge]>14)` and `=Count([MaxofAge])>14` and every other variation possible, but I just can't get it to work.

Answer (score 2):

Use an `IIf()` expression which returns 1 if `[MaxOfAge]>14` and zero otherwise.  Then nest that `IIf()` in `Sum()`.

```vb
=Sum(IIf([MaxOfAge]>14, 1, 0))
```

Comment: Awesome that worked beautifully.  I think I was just stuck in Excel expression mode where sum adds totals not records.  Thanks.